# Sumologic and Android Tablet

Tags: android, ios, sumologic

I have a sumologic query that returns the OS / Browser based on the user-agent.

I've trying to twek this query to differentiate between mobile / tablet / desktop.

This is quite easy when it come to Apple as you can get the iPad / iPhone from the user-agent very easily.

Now, for Android, I can't work it out.

If I use matches:

```
| if (agent matches "*Android Tablet*","Tablet",device) as device
```

It looks like I will get the tablets (running on Android).

But, if I add this line:

```
| if (agent matches "*Android*","Mobile",device) as device
```

It will get me the phones and tablets ...

Any idea how to change this:

```
| if (agent matches "*Android Tablet*","Tablet",device) as device 
| if (agent matches "*Android*","Mobile",device) as device
```

to get tablet and mobile on Android ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the order to:

```
| if (agent matches "*Android*","Mobile",device) as device 
| if (agent matches "*Android Tablet*","Tablet",device) as device
```